# Using Reflection to create a Mock of an interface that is unknown during buildtime

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, rhino-mocks, end-to-end

For my ned to end testing it is important that my testassembly does not preload a shadowcopy of a dependent assembly.

Assembly T is the Testframework that loads and tests Assembly A.
Assembly A depends on interfaces defined in B.

For testing purposes i have to replace some static members in A without having them available during buildtime.

Here is some pseudo code that illustrates the dilemma i am in:

```
        A_assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("A.dll");
        A_type = A_assembly.GetType("TheSingleton.Master", true);
        MethodInfo Master_Init_Info = type.GetMethod("Init", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
        //before init is called some things need to be replaced
        FieldInfo semiknown = A_type.GetField("needsmocking", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static));
        ??? mock_semiknown = MockRepository.GenerateMock<???>();
        semiknown.SetValue((???)mock_semiknown, mock_semiknown);
        //testing makes only sense if that static is replaced.
        Master_Init_Info.Invoke(null, null);
```

1. I can access the type via `semiknown.FieldType` but what good does
   that do me? Can i use that information somehow to create the mock
   and replace the static member with it?
2. Suppose i get the type and am able to replace the static member -
   how can i build my expectancies in the mock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it by reflection

```
var method = typeof(MockRepository).GetMethod("GenerateMock").MakeGenericMethod(semiknown.FieldType);
var mock_semiknown = method.Invoke(null, null);
```